# Upgrade Mediawiki on a Windows Server 2003 box?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, wiki, mediawiki

I was wondering if anyone knew the location or had any experience updating media wiki to the newest version

1.15.1

I see lots of documentation for Linux installs but i can't seem find any for Windows.

I just "inherited" this box and don't usually handle this type of stuff so any step by step guide would be great.

Comment: Apparently you can't use markup in comments. Unbutchered link:

http://serverfault.com/questions/42256/media-wiki-on-windows-server-2k3-backup-restore-and-upgrade/42263

Comment: I did ask nearly identical but not identical. The answers I got for the previous question were all backup in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the upgrade stuff happens in the database, the operating system on the server shouldn't make a massive difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded MediaWiki on W2K3 many times - the official upgrade instructions are fine. Go for it :)

Answer (score -1):

You upload the new files then run the upgrade script as described in the upgrade readme file. That file/documentation isn't linux based,it's the same no matter what operating system your install is running on.